# jQuery Add/Remove Current with Element Id

Tags: jquery, menu, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to 
1) apply "current" class to link (id="book") as default when the page is first loaded, and 
2) when a link in the ul "submenu" is clicked, add "current" to its class and remove "current" from the previous "current" link. I'm a beginner so please explain in the simplest terms. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCurrent(obj){
$('ul#submenu li a').each(function(){   
    $('.current').removeClass('current'); 
});
$(obj).addClass('current');
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setCurrent('book')">
<div id="container">
<div id="content-top"></div>
<div id="content-left"></div>
<div id="content-main">
    <iframe src="port_book.html" name="contentframe" align="middle" scrolling="no" id="contentframe"></iframe>     
</div>  
<div id="content-right"></div>
<div id="content-bottom">
    <ul id="submenu">
    <li><a onclick="setCurrent(this);" href="port_book.html" id="book" target="contentframe">book</a><span class="bar">|</span></li>
    <li><a onclick="setCurrent(this);" href="port_poster.html" id="poster" target="contentframe">poster</a><span class="bar">|</span></li>
    <li><a onclick="setCurrent(this);" href="port_annual_report.html" id="annualreport" target="contentframe">annual report</a><span class="bar">|</span></li>
    <li><a onclick="setCurrent(this);" href="port_branding.html" id="branding" target="contentframe">branding</a><span class="bar">|</span></li>
    <li><a onclick="setCurrent(this);" href="port_packaging.html" id="packaging" target="contentframe">packaging</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
ul#submenu li{
color: #770046;
}
ul#submenu li a{
color: #333;
}
ul#submenu li.current a{
color: #770046;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove the `onclick` from your links:

```
 onclick="setCurrent(this);"
```

Then add this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { // On page load
  $("#book").addClass("current"); // Add ".current" to "#book"
  $("ul#submenu li a").on("click", function() { // When a link clicked
    if( !$(this).hasClass("current") ) // If link has not already have a "current" class
    {
      $('ul#submenu li a').each(function(){ // For each link
        $(this).removeClass("current"); // Remove "current" class
      });
      $(this).addClass("current"); // Add "current" class to the clicked link
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

If you are sure that the links won't have any other`class`, then instead of `$(this).removeClass("current");`, use this:

```
$(this).removeAttr('class'); // Removes the whole `class` attribute
```

Another way to remove the "current" class is using attribute `selectors`:

```
$("ul#submenu li a[class*=current]").removeClass('current'); // IE8+, Webkit, Opera, Mozzila
```

**To summarize, best approach:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#book").addClass("current");
  $("ul#submenu li a").on("click", function() {
    if( !$(this).hasClass("current") ) 
    {
      $("ul#submenu li a[class*=current]").removeClass('current');
      $("ul#submenu li a[class='']").removeAttr('class');
      $(this).addClass("current");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, nothing has changed. The link with id "book" isn't set as current on default and when other links are clicked, they aren't being changed to the CSS of current link. I've posted the revised codes below hoping I can get further help trouble shooting this. Thanks.

Comment: @user2154961: It's because you have a problem in your css. Change this `ul#submenu li.current a` to this `ul#submenu li a.current`. It's working fine. Check the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MF4pu/

Comment: But! I think you want to achieve something totally different... I don't see you loading data asynchronously, therefore when you click on a link a new page will load. And if you have this same menu in the loaded pages, the `#book` will always show as `current`. **SO** what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've modified the CSS as instructed and it still doesn't work. I think it's because the content are being loaded into an iframe. But I'm still not sure how to do this. Here is my website: http://khuudesigns.com/ When the Portfolio is loaded initially, the "book" gallery will load into the iframe in the middle of the page so I want the link "book" to have the css style of current. Then when another link is clicked, the "book" link goes back to normal (gray), and the corresponding link will have the style of current. I apologize for poor communication skill and appreciate your patience. Thanks.

Comment: You are not loading the jQuery library. Add this to the head of your page: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That does it! Thanks you very much! It totally slipped my mind to load the jQuery library on my page. And your quick response is greatly appreciated!